# TFS search dialog for items

Tags: tfs

Has the team explorer a search dialog for TFS items without to create a query?
Are there any third party tools for searching TFS items with full-text searches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a plugin called [Search Work Items](http://www.codeplex.com/searchworkitems).

Comment: nice add-on, it does what i want!

Answer (score 0):

The Search Work Items plugin doesn't work with multiple words across fields, so you cant do things like "system crash jrodgers", "system crash State:active", "(system or fatal) crash -closed".

If you want true full text search, you can use this: http://teamsearchapp.com

Disclaimer: I built the product at that address, so take my advice for what it is worth...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, http://www.teamcompanion.com a 3rd Party TFS tool in Outlook.

You get a nice UI to create queries.